# Retain only alphanumeric values from all cells in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook with multiple sheets, I want to retain only A-Z, 0-9, and ".". in all the cells in every sheet of the workbook.

I thought of using the following:

```
Function AlphaNumericOnly(strSource As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strResult As String

    For i = 1 To Len(strSource)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(strSource, i, 1))
            Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122: 'include 32 if you want to include space
                strResult = strResult & Mid(strSource, i, 1)
        End Select
    Next
    AlphaNumericOnly = strResult
End Function
```

But running this function just yields #NAME? in excel

Also I want the excel to automatically navigate to new sheets and do the same for say a fixed range of data.

Can anyone help me here.

Thanks in advance

P.S: using Mac office 2016, the workbook has 30 sheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#NAME` error comes from Excel being unable to recognize the custom function. If you are **sure** that it is not misspelled then the next most likely issue is that it has been put in the wrong place.

A User Defined Function (aka UDF) is placed into a standard module code sheet. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to **Insert ► Module** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the function code into the new module code sheet titled something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet(s).

[image: udf_placement]